# How to use pyi type hints for a classes with dynamic inheritance

Tags: python, mypy

I have a python library where I'm keeping all type hints in a ".pyi" sidecar file. There are several reasons for this that I don't want to bikeshed about.

What I do want is to better understand how to use .pyi files to correctly type annotate my library. The situation I have is this. I am extending `pathlib.Path`, which is a very weird class when it comes to typing. I've gone through several iterations and finally settled on the (roughly) following code:

```py
### other code

import pathlib

_PathBase = pathlib.WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else pathlib.PosixPath


class Path(_PathBase):
    """
    An extension of :class:`pathlib.Path` with extra convenience methods
    """

    def shrinkuser(self, home='~'):
        """
        Inverse of :func:`os.path.expanduser`.

        Args:
            home (str, default='~'): symbol used to replace the home path.
                Defaults to '~', but you might want to use '$HOME' or
                '%USERPROFILE%' instead.

        Returns:
            Path: path - shortened path replacing the home directory with a symbol

        Example:
            >>> import ubelt as ub
            >>> path = ub.Path('~').expand()
            >>> assert str(path.shrinkuser()) == '~'
            >>> assert str(ub.Path((str(path) + '1')).shrinkuser()) == str(path) + '1'
            >>> assert str((path / '1').shrinkuser()) == join('~', '1')
            >>> assert str((path / '1').shrinkuser('$HOME')) == join('$HOME', '1')
            >>> assert str(ub.Path('.').shrinkuser()) == '.'
        """
        shrunk = shrinkuser(str(self), home)
        new = self.__class__(shrunk)
        return new
```

I then have a script that parses the google-style docstrings and generates the pyi type stubs.

The generated .pyi stub looks like this:

```py
class Path(_PathBase):
    def shrinkuser(self, home: str = ...) -> 'Path':
        ...
```

The issue is that `_PathBase` is not defined, and when I manually hack it to include something like `_PathBase = pathlib.WindowsPath if os.name == 'nt' else pathlib.PosixPath`, mypy says it is "not valid as a type".

If I remove the inheriting class from the type annotation, mypy seems happy with the stub, but I don't know if this is correct or not. My question is: can I just remove the parent class from the stub, or will that break something? If not, what is the right way to denote that a class (in this case `Path`) could inherit from one of some set of classes (in this case either `pathlib.PosixPath` or `pathlib.WindowsPath`?

Comment: It's not valid as a *static* type, which is what `mypy` checks. `_PathBase` doesn't have a static value because the value of `os.name` isn't known until runtime.

Comment: Is there a way I can denote what the types could be?

Comment: Why not just use `pathlib.Path`, which is *already* an abstraction away from platform-specific details implemented by the two subclasses?

Comment: Because pathlib.Path overloads `__new__`, and actually will replace the instantiated class with `pathlib.WindowsPath` or `pathlib.PosixPath`. It's very strange, but I understand why they did it, but it does make inheriting from pathlib.Path a lot tricker.